# React - Dynamic image rendering stutters when bundled/live

Tags: javascript, image, reactjs, components

I have an issue with a component that takes a name property for use as an avatar (replaces spaces with dashes and adds file format). This then gets used as the img src dynamically.

Works absolutely fine locally, no stuttering changing the image. When I bundle and deploy to surge.sh and change routes the image stutters. I expected this as each image needs to be downloaded initially but even after the image is cached, swapping the image is jerky. Any ideas? Or is there a better way to do this?

```
class Athlete extends Component {
    constructor (props) {
        super(props);
    }

    render () {
        let name = this.props.name;
        let imgName = name.replace(/\s+/g, '-').toLowerCase();
        let imgSrc = '/img/athletes/' + imgName + '.jpg';

        return (

            <div className="winner__inner">
                <img src={imgSrc} alt={name} className="winner__avatar"/>
                <h3 className="winner__name">{name}</h3>
            </div>

        );
    }
}

export default Athlete;
```

Link: http://boulder.surge.sh/ (desktop only - click one of the events)

GIF: https://i.gyazo.com/4dea5302d9671b4de0fadc2334f872da.gif

Cached images: https://i.stack.imgur.com/RMMb1.png

Any help would be great, thanks!

Comment: It seems only some of the images are cached. Dont you have a service worker ?

Comment: Not sure why only some are getting cached. Not using a service worker. Could this be due to it being hosted via surge?